# check instance of sql server is running

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, service, smo

How to check a particular instance of sql server is running or not which is installed in a network pc(not in local pc) by using vb.net. 
I can try to open a connection and check for timeout and find that connection failed.But i don't want it to do that way.So please come up with any other solution

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a DataTable with the information about all the connected SQL Servers as described [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx) and check if the one that you are looking for is listed or not.

Sample code

```
Dim DataTable1 As DataTable = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources
```